# Searching with regex for a number of names in a list?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm unsure how to complete the regex shown in the search below, as I'm trying to count how many names there are in each list within my items list.

#### Code Snippit

```
items = ["List: Name-Here", "List: Name-Here, Here, Here'Here, Here-Here'Here, Here Here Here", "List: Here, Here Here, Here Here Here Here"]

for item in items:
    pull1 = re.search(r'(List:)\s+', item)
    pull1 = len(pull1.split(","))
    print pull1,"\n"
```

#### Expected Output:

```
1
5
3
```

Any ideas?
- Hyflex

Comment: Why you need a regex?

Comment: @RohitJain Because my original text the "items" isn't populated, I'm trying to find it within a block of text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex isn't needed here.  All of your names are comma-separated.  So, you can get what you want by just splitting on that:

```
>>> items = ["List: Name-Here", "List: Name-Here, Here, Here'Here, Here-Here'Here, Here Here Here", "List: Here, Here Here, Here Here Here Here"]
>>> [len(x.split(",")) for x in items]
[1, 5, 3]
>>>
```

---

**Edit in response to comment:**

I think this is what you want:

```
from re import findall

mystr = """
List: Name-Here
List: Name-Here, Here, Here'Here, Here-Here'Here, Here Here Here
List: Here, Here Here, Here Here Here Here
"""

items = findall("List:(.+)", mystr)
for item in items:
    print len(item.split(","))
```

output:

```
1
5
3
```

Comment: Hopefully `"List:"` is not a valid item.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski - The OP's goal was to _count_ the names, not print them.  So yes, `"List:"` will be captured, but it isn't a problem here.

Comment: It will be counted as `1`, but since there is no name in `"List:"`, should it not be counted as `0`?  Of course, I have no idea whether `"List:"` is a valid item.  And if it is, I have no idea how it should be counted.

Comment: @iCodez I said regex because my original text the "items" isn't populated, I'm trying to find it within a block of text and as for the point Steven pulls up, that can be bypassed easy if it counts that.

Comment: @Hyflex - Oh.  Well, the splitting is still the right answer.  What you need is a way to capture text and make it in a list like you gave.  See my edit--I think it will work for you.